# I want to use python option -m when i use pycharm debugger

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, command-line-arguments

Hi I got the project on the github, I want to analyze this code using debugging.
The project uses python 3.6 and requires next command when running

```
python -m pixloc.run_Aachen
```

pixloc is package (directory) name and run_Aachen is python file name.

When I run this command using Pycharm, It is successful

but When I run this using Pycharm Debug mode, It is fail

the following image is my Run/Debug Configuration

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7Tiu.png)

What can I do for this problem

I try to use setuptools.setup(), but this isn't work
I just want to use -m option in debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your run configuration is currently set to to run a Python script (i.e., as `python ./path/to/script.py`), but you want to execute a module (i.e., `python -m package.subpack.mod`).

To change your run configuration to one that executes a module, do the following:

1. Under the run configuration, click on the first dropdown that reads "Script path" and change it to "Module name".
2. Then, specify `pixloc.run_Aachen` in accompanying testbox.

Comment: OH, Thank you for your fast Answer!

Comment: I have a question, -m option is written in Interpreter option?

Comment: @S.M.K Yes, [`-m` is a interpreter option](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m). You can read more about the effects of running a file as a script vs as a module in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14132912/11082165).

Comment: Wow... I'm so thankful that I don't know what to do. I just accepte your answer. Thank you so much. Now, I can study the paper Thank you